# JAX-WS and sun-jaxws.xml

Tags: web-services, jax-ws

I have read a lot of posts on public forums about deploying JAX-WS on different servet containers
and I have following questions/queries based on that.

Following is my understanding :

1)`sun-jaxws.xml` is required ONLY BY Sun's RI (metro project) since `com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener` class needs it.
(looking at source for this class , it reads this file from hardcoded location).

2)It is also required if servlet container is not `Java EE 5 compliant.`

3)Different application servers like `Jboss , GlassFish` can use their own JAX-WS implementations (like `Apache CXF,Metro`)

So my questions are :

1)If I use Sun's RI (metro) on Java EE 5 container like JBoss or GlassFish , do I still need to use `sun-jaxs.xml` ?

2)If I develope JAX-WS web service on Java EE 5 container like Jboss , can it be portable to another Java EE 5 container like GlassFish. What I mean is can I deploy the war as it is on another container ?

Please help me sort out above queries since I am really confused about Sun's RI and `sun-jaxws.xml` descriptor usage.

Answer (score 1):

Application servers have own web service client frameworks. You can think these are like jaxws. When you deploy an app to app server default option app server use own framework for web service call. Therefore if server need a configuration file like as sun-jaxws.xml you must put it relevant directory. But I dont think you need it.

Second option is configuring the app server for using your third part jax-ws library. It is an extra option. For example I made in WAS. Because of that when you choose this choice you must use sun-jaxws.xml

Hopefully I have been clear in my answer :)

Comment: Thanks for answer. So if I understand correctly , every app server (Java EE 5 compliant) , uses its own reference implementation for JAX-WS. If we want to use any third party libs , do extra configuration. Have you used Metro on WAS ? Does that require you to use sun-jaxws.xml ?

Comment: Yes i used.  For deployment it is required. but i used jax ws 2.2.8, metro library is extended version.